# How to modify the following code to include file path

Tags: excel, vba

How can I modify the following code to give me the entire file path rather than just the file name?

```
Sub GetFileNames()
Dim xRow As Long
Dim xDirect$, xFname$, InitialFoldr$

InitialFoldr$ = "C:\"
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath & "\"
    .Title = "Please select a folder to list Files from"
    .InitialFileName = InitialFoldr$
    .Show
    If .SelectedItems.Count <> 0 Then
        xDirect$ = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
        xFname$ = Dir(xDirect$, 7)
        Do While xFname$ <> ""
            ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xFname$
            xRow = xRow + 1
            xFname$ = Dir
        Loop
    End If
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: When I run the full code and it prompts me for the folder that contains the files, it only returns the file names in excel and not the entire path. In excel I'd like to see the whole thing spelled out rather than just the file names but I don't know what to edit to return the entire path in excel.

Comment: if you add `Debug.Print xDirect$` and `xFname$` you would figured it out

Comment: For future refference, try not to use `ActiveCell`, try to use qualified `Range`, such as `Worksheets("MeaningfulSheetName").Range("A" & RowNum).Value = xDirect$ & xFname$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try...

```
ActiveCell.Offset(xRow) = xDirect$ & xFname$
```

Comment: Oh... kinda feel dumb now, I see what Shai meant now... uhm thanks. -_-

Comment: You're welcome. Don't worry. It happens with all of us. :)